# Path get extra backslashes when retrieved from database

Tags: asp.net

I'm working on a script that picks file from one location (source) and copies to another location (destination). The script is working file if the path is provided directly. But I want path to be retrieved from a database.

While storing path in database the path is **@"D:\test"** but when the path is retrieved it comes out as **"@\"D:\test\""**

I'm using ASP.Net as a platform for this. Please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.   We will need more information to help you.  What is the code that you are using to store the path in the database?  What code are you using to retrieve it?   How do you know that it contains the extra backslashes?   Is the "@" part of the path?

Comment: Did you store the path value with the @ and the " attached?

Comment: @Steve I've appended the @ before inserting in the database, and yes @ is part of the path

I'm using ASP.net using C#

**string src_e = "@" + '"' + src + '"';**

**string dest_e = "@" + '"' + dest + '"';**

Comment: Why do you add the @ and the double quotes? They are not needed to store a path in the database, just pass src to your inserting db code

Answer (score 0):

use split() method to remove those extra backslsh

str = str.replaceAll("\", "\");
or

str = str.replace("\", "");

Comment: How does he strip only the ones that were added, and not ones that are part of the path?

Comment: This is the code I'm using to store path in the database
 string src = text_source.Text;          //stores source location
        string dest = text_destination.Text;    // stores destination location
        string src_e = "@" + '"' + src + '"';
        string dest_e = "@" + '"' + dest + '"';

and to retrieve m using this code

dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                st3 = dr["source"].ToString();
                st4 = dr["destination"].ToString();
            }
        }